# Bootstrap DatePicker Is Not Working All The Required Files Have Been Added

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I have Used The Following Code To Initialize The DatePicker

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>  
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/datepicker.css" />
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="input-group date" data-provide="datepicker">
    <input type="text" class="form-control">
    <div class="input-group-addon">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span>
    </div>
</div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript"> 
        $(document).ready(function (){

        $('.datepicker').datepicker();


        });

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Still The DatePicker Is Not Working ... Can Someone Guide Me Where Have I Been Wrong ... Thanks.

Comment: see the error in console

Comment: inspect element in browser and see the console tab

Comment: There Is No Error In the Console @jothi

Comment: add the class like this in your input  <input type="text" class="form-control  datepicker">

Comment: Hey Thanks Alot @jothi.  That Works Fine

Comment: if my answer is useful to you make it green tick .its useful to future user

Comment: I have done It Thanks Alot @jothi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you forgot to add `class name` in your datepicker input field

```
 <input type="text" class="form-control datepicker">
```